# authentication for wkhtmltopdf on domino server

Tags: session-cookies, lotus-domino, wkhtmltopdf, ibm-domino

I am trying to login on the domino server using --custom-header and http username without success:

```
wkhtmltopdf --custom-header Username Mxxxx --custom-header Password xxxxxxx http://server/database.nsf/view/B067E9B04AC2B3FAC225835C004D211B thedoc.pdf

wkhtmltopdf --username Mxxxx --password xxxx  http://server/database.nsf/view/B067E9B04AC2B3FAC225835C004D211B thedoc.pdf
```

I found in another post about making a cookie and use it during generation of pdfs, but I did not find yet samples of how these session cookies made and used by wkhtmltopdf.

So my current question are:
Why would the username switches not work?
Any samples of making such session cookies for Domino server or similar?
In case of two word username. how it is put in the command (e.g. with single quotes)?

[image]

Comment: have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019603/wkhtmltopdf-and-forms-based-authentication

Comment: The reason for this is that wkhtmltopdf expects basic auth.