# using wkhtmltopdf with multiple raw html strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, wkhtmltopdf

I am using c# to call `wkhtmltopdf.exe` from the command line. I want to pass in the html as a string as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6787041/2600398). How can I pass in multiple html files?

I have tried the following:

```
StreamWriter stdin = p.StandardInput;
stdin.AutoFlush = false;
foreach (string html in htmlStringsList)
{
   stdin.WriteLine(html);
}
stdin.Flush();
stdin.Dispose();
```

But I just get a pdf with all of the html documents overlayed on top of each other on the same page. How do I get each html document to start on a new page?

Comment: Any solutions? i am having the same task.